# Echo not outputting variable value

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to print value of API_RESPONSE but it prints `"response is: "`. S3_RESPONSE value is set but API_RESPONSE shows blank in echo command.

```
  - name: Check if certificate exists
    id: check_certificate
    run: |
      API_RESPONSE=$(aws s3api head-object --bucket test-bucket-ssl --key fullchain.pem 2>&1 | tee true)
      echo "::set-output name=S3_RESPONSE::$(echo $API_RESPONSE)"
      echo "response is: ${API_RESPONSE}"
```

Comment: I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73010822/6309) with a new root cause: the `tee true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the GitHub action is unable to set or print the value of `API_RESPONSE` because of the `tee true` command in your script.
[The `tee` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) in Unix/Linux is used to store and view (both at the same time) the output of any other command.

Here, you are trying to store the output of the `aws s3api head-object` command and then print it to a file named `true`. This is likely causing the problem with `API_RESPONSE` being empty, as the output is not being stored in the variable as expected.

Try instead:

```yaml
- name: Check if certificate exists
  id: check_certificate
  run: |
    API_RESPONSE=$(aws s3api head-object --bucket test-bucket-ssl --key fullchain.pem 2>&1)
    echo "::set-output name=S3_RESPONSE::$API_RESPONSE"
    echo "response is: $API_RESPONSE"
```

In this corrected script, the output of the `aws s3api head-object` command will be stored in `API_RESPONSE`. The `2>&1` redirects both standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`) to the variable `API_RESPONSE`.

Also, note that when you are setting an output variable in GitHub Actions, you do not need to use `$(echo $API_RESPONSE)`. Simply using `$API_RESPONSE` should be enough.

Make sure that your AWS command is working as expected and returning the desired output: if the command does not return any output or returns an error, the `API_RESPONSE` variable will still be empty.